# My second javaScript slideshow is using the pictures from the first one

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I am making a quiz to practice html css and javaScipt, I wanted slideshows above each questions. When I made the second slideshow it plugged in two pictures from the first one. I'm not sure what the problem with it is

this is the code from the first slideshow :

```
<img id="question1" style="margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px;">
        <h1>"I'm the foot master, I got my technique down and everything.." Is said by which character?</h1>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var imgArray2 =["images/jules.png",
                "images/vega.png",
                    "images/pink.png",
                "images/worley.png"
                            ];

        var curIndex2 = 0;
        var imgDuration2 = 4000;

        function q1slideShow() {
                document.getElementById("question1").src= imgArray2[curIndex2];
        curIndex2++;
        if(curIndex2 == imgArray2.length) { curIndex2 = 0;
            }
        setTimeout("q1slideShow()", imgDuration2);
        }
        q1slideShow();
    </script>
```

this is the code from the second slideshow:

```
        <img id="question2" style="margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px;">
    <h1>Whatis the name of Quentin Tarantino's characterin" Reservoir Dogs?"</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var imgArray3 =["images/rDogs1.png",
            "images/rDogs2.png",
            "images/rDogs3.png",
            "images/rDogs4.png"
    ];

    var curIndex3 = 0;
    var imgDuration3 = 4000;

    function q2slideShow() {
                          document.getElementById("question2").src= imgArray3[curIndex3];
        curIndex3++;
        if(curIndex3 == imgArray3.length) {
        curIndex3 = 0;
            }
    setTimeout("q2slideShow()", imgDuration3);
        }
        q2slideShow();
    </script>
```

I'm not sure if the problem is with the ID's or if I'm simply appying the wrong javaScript concepts.

Comment: Just taking a look, but there are a few changes you should really make to your code. 1. Img tags should have a close e.g. <img src="" /> 2. You can use modulus instead of testing if the index is bigger than your array e.g. curIndex3 = curIndex3 % imageArray3.length 3. You shouldn't pass strings into setTimeouts, it's slow e.g. setTimeout(q2slideShow, imgDuration3); Let me know if you'd like a better explanation of any of that. :)

Comment: Stuck your code on jsfiddle and cleaned it up a little, but it seems to be running fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Z4NYL/ What browser are you testing in?

Comment: I got it running, turns out it was because I had pasted the same script in the whole document to modify for each slideshow.I guess because ID's were matching it ruined the slideshow. Now I'm just going to retype it as I need it instead of putting it all in at once. It'd be cool to go over the modulus concept though.

Comment: Wikipedia sums it up nicely: "modulo (sometimes calledmodulus) operation finds the remainder of division of one number by another." So in my example: curIndex = curIndex % imageArray.length if curIndex was 4 and imageArray.length was 4 the result would be 0 as the number can fit into the other exactly with no remainder. If curIndex were 5 and the array was 4 it would result in 1 as 4 fits into 5 with an extra 1. :)